# function and method and str or return issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encryption

so i have a program that takes a description, password,and key. but when i put the password and key into the encrypt method i get errors when i try to get a return due to it being a function, so how do i get around this?

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key):
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-"
cipher = " "
for c in plaintext:
    if c in alphabet:
        cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) + key) % (len(alphabet))]
print("Your encrypeted msg is: ", cipher)
return cipher


def decrypt(cryptedtext, key):
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-"
cipher = " "

for c in cryptedtext:
    if c in alphabet:
        cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(c) - key) % len(alphabet)]
print("decrypt: ", cipher)


def EnterInfo():
entry = input(" please enter in des to be stored")
entry2 = input(" please enter in pass to be stored")
entry3 = int(input(" please enter in key to be stored"))
encrypt(entry2, entry3)
entry2 = encrypt
with open("test.txt", 'a') as myfile:
    myfile.write(entry + ":" + entry2 + ":\n")

EnterInfo()
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/yoyo/PycharmProjects/crypt/CombineCryptAndTxtPyFile.py", line 29, in EnterInfo
myfile.write(entry + ":" + entry2 + ":\n")
TypeError: Can't convert 'function' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: the indentation in your code snippet is messed up. there's nothing in each of the function definitions. can you fix the indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mishandling function usage:

```
encrypt(entry2, entry3)
entry2 = encrypt
```

In the first line, you call the `encrypt` function on `entry2` and `entry3` and it returns the result, which is then immediately thrown away because you haven't assigned it to anything.

Then in second line, you set `entry2` equal to the *function* `encrypt`, not the result of your previous function call. So you are trying to concatenate a string and a function which has no string equivalent.

Instead, assign the result of the `encrypt` call to a variable, and use that result in your `write` call.

Example:

```
result = encrypt(entry1, entry2)
```